# G is a graph with n points.If it exists a number c > 0,,makes that g(G) ≥ cn.(g(G) is the girth of the G).How to prove that e(G) ≤ n + o(n)?

Tags: graph-theory

> Suppose $G$ is a graph with $n$ points. If it exists a number $c > 0$, makes that $g(G) ≥ cn\cdot\left(g(G) \text { is the girth of the G}\right)$. How to prove that $e(G) ≤ n + o(n)$?

I want to use mathematical induction to solve this question, but there is no good idea of using mathematical induction. I want to change this question to a normal graph that only has cyclic with length $[cn]$, and try to think the situation has the most edges, but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this question by myself.Just think about c=1/2^n(n=0,1,2,3...),and for graph G, divide points of G to two part and use mathematical induction to n will solve this question.